# Short story about a robot teacher controlling the narrative given to young minds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I'm trying to find the name of a short story I read in an English class anthology textbook from my junior high days (about 1985, so the story pre-dates that).

The story is similar in several ways to Isaac Asimov's ***The Fun They Had***, but differs in key aspects.

Basically, as I recall, a young brother and sister (or maybe it was just one child) are "in school", meaning learning from their robot or computer teacher at home.
The subject comes up about how children in the past gathered together in real school buildings, and learned from human teachers.
The children ask what happened? What changed?
The computer informs them that human teachers became disruptive to the government, went on strikes, taught unapproved lessons, etc..
The government, to serve the children better, replaced human teachers with robot/computer teachers, and now everyone is happier. (There might be an implication that the disruptive teachers are gathered up and disposed of)
The children accept this blandly, knowing that the computer teacher is always right.

I remember the moral of the story being that whoever has exclusive control of the narrative given to young minds, controls the truth.

Does anyone else remember this story? What was it called?

Comment: Sounds like someone read it and used it as an instruction manual. :(